# Upload data to Exasol from python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, exasolution, exasol

I wonder if there's anyways to upload a dataframe and create a new table in Exasol? import_from_pandas assumes the table already exists. Do we need to run a SQL separately to create the table? for other databases, to_sql can just create the table if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As you mentioned `import_from_pandas` requires a table. So, you need to create a table before writing to it. You can run a SQL `create table ...` script by `connection.execute` before using `import_from_pandas`. Also `to_sql` needs a table since based on the documentation it will be translated to a SQL `insert` command.

Answer (score 0):

`Pandas` [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) allows to create a new table if it does not exist, but it needs an `SQLAlchemy` connection, which is not supported for `Exasol` out of the box. However, there seems to be a SQLAlchemy [dialect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/) for Exasol you could use (haven't tried it yet): [sqlalchemy-exasol](https://github.com/exasol/sqlalchemy-exasol).

Alternatively, I think you have to use a `create table` statement and then populate the table via `pyexasol`'s `import_from_pandas`.